# How do I learn to design a UI like this?

Tags: android, user-interface

I was recently using the app [`Secret`](https://www.secret.ly/) and was observing the amazing user-interface that it has. *If you are opening Secret's webpage, please scroll down a little to see the UI.*

Being someone who is still a novice in Android and wants to learn, **I would like to ask how that UI has been designed.** I could ask a lot many questions in this one post but I will limit myself to just one for now.

Whenever you click on one of those tiles, it opens up and shows the comments for that particular tile. The other tiles below and above disappear. When you click on the tile again, it smoothly animates back to its position and the tiles above and below come into view. How is this achieved?

*What have I tried so far?* Nothing, because it is a "where do I begin?" question.

Comment: Nothing more than a custom ListView...

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Then let's bring it to life. Temme more :)

Comment: Here's a tutorial on a custom ListView. Its row uses an ImageView and two TextViews. In your case, the row should be engineered to have a big image above, a Text in the middle and some controls on the bottom - a RelativeLayout will be a perfect container. http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably an instance of a **custom activity transition** (and a particularly well polished one).

In general, you can use the [`overridePendingTransition()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29) to specify an animation that must be run when the current activity is changed (a classic example is sliding in a new Activity from a direction, while the previous Activity exits in the opposite direction). However, these transitions generally do not share UI elements.

Chet Haase has done a few DevBytes (in particular [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA#t=327)) to "simulate" an activity transition that *shares an UI element* (i.e. a view) between the caller and called activities. For example, if you have a Gallery, and you click on an image to show it full-screen, you would probably want the image to "grow" smoothly until it occupies this new position. The trick to achieve this is to actually *disable the standard transitions entirely* and include in the `Intent` used to start the activity the information about the current position and dimensions of the view that you want to "share":

```
Intent subActivity = new Intent(this, PictureDetailsActivity.class);
subActivity.putExtra(PACKAGE + ".left", screenLocation[0]);
subActivity.putExtra(PACKAGE + ".top", screenLocation[1]);
subActivity.putExtra(PACKAGE + ".width", v.getWidth());
subActivity.putExtra(PACKAGE + ".height", v.getHeight());

startActivity(subActivity);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Therefore, the new activity can extract this data, and with this information and the knowledge of *where on the screen the view should end up*, can build and execute an animation that simulates the desired effect.

This technique can be difficult to implement if you want a complex animation, so in *Android L* this was baked into the platform itself: [Activity Transitions](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html#transitions) can handle this automatically and provide a few built-in animations to act on the remaining (i.e. non shared) views. For example, the *explode* transition seems to be very much like the one you describe.

Comment: I read the comment posted. Can this be implemented easily with a custom list view? I mean, `getView()` magic?  When you click, list item moves to top. Every list item has a `ViewStub` which becomes visible and so on?

Comment: @LittleChild I'm not sure about the "easily" part. This isn't rocket science, but it's not the simplest task either. :/ I recommend you take a look at the DevByte to understand the technique better.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding layouts: 
You might find it helpful to use hierarchy viewer, which offers a function to capture the layers of the UI and store them in a Photoshop file. This gives you a good idea how the layout of a particular app you are was created and what kind of views were used.

Regarding animations:
Checkout videos by Chet Haase and Romain Guy who discuss graphics and animations in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the Android training guides.

[This one](http://developer.android.com/training/building-graphics.html) is an overview of designing with media and animation, but [this one](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) uses a ViewPager to achieve the effect you want.