# Android Material design transitions

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

I want to replicate the transitions as explained in Material design by Google.
This is the [link for the preview](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/meaningful-transitions.html#meaningful-transitions-meaningful-transitions-examples), but basically the videos I care about are those two:

1. http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animations-meaningfultransitions-hierarchical_transitions_topLevel_large_xhdpi.webm
2. http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animation-meaningfultransitions-view_contact_large_xhdpi.webm

My question is what is the container of the UI? Is this a new Activity which onCreate has animations for each element or is it a fragment?

In particular on the second example there is some movement on the 1st Activity so inside the  onClick is there an animation which also creates a 2nd activity? (note that the clicked name also moves, so this should not be a new activity)

In other words what the layout (+Activities, fragments) should be if I want to replicate this?

Comment: This is exactly me question too!

Comment: I'm eager to learn how this is done as well, especially the first animation, which has an equally expanding frame that hits the edges and then expands only vertically.  I want to use this with a Fragment, but I suspect on Jelly Bean and earlier it's not possible.

Comment: These tranisitons are basically working on scenes. Scenes are nothing but  layouts. So on one activity you can have any number of scenes depending on your click.

Take a look at this video you sent
http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animations-meaningfultransitions-hierarchical_transitions_topLevel_large_xhdpi.webm

The first layout you see is SCENE 1 ,when the click happens and other layout opens that is SCENE 2. So the activity on which these two scenes are placed is the same.

That is my understanding of this concept. But the concept is new so more research is needed

Comment: The funniest thing is, that even with the addition of the Transition Framework, you'll not be able to create an animation that is as smooth as the provided examples xD Phony stuff ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe too late but I have found support library contains `ActivityOptionsCompat`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html
It contains activity animations like scale up animations. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is a great answer. I'm looking at the possibilities of `makeCustomAnimation()`. Will come back to you

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question?

Comment: `ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(....)` and then `startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle())` will do the trick

Answer (score 5):

This one have transitions.

Hope you'll extract transitions from there.

Guide - http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/
Code - https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterialEverywhere

Answer (score 4):

I guess they could be implemented with fragments but I might suspect they would be separate activities. Android L introduces *Activity Transitions* as part of the Animation framework. In particular, there transitions can contain *shared UI elements*, which indicate mappings between "corresponding" views in the caller and called activities. The transition is then included as part of the [`ActivityOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html) object passed to `startActivity()`.

The idea is to achieve the visual effect in those videos (i.e. of particular views changing positions or dimensions as part of an activity transition). The canonical example would be a Gallery app, when transitioning from the grid that shows all images to displaying a particular one.

This *could* be achieved before (please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24502443/82788) or [this DevBytes video by Chet Haase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA#t=327)) but it was rather complex/hacky so it was included as a standard resource in Android L.

Check the documentation for [Activity Transitions](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html#transitions) in the L preview documentation, or the `ActivitySceneTransitionBasic` included as part of the android-L samples (also remember that you can download the L reference preview from [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/reference.html) to get the documentation for the new methods).

Comment: Is this applicable also to ActivityOptionsCompat in support package? I tried it, but I didnt succeed

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:Consider that you are moving from one activity to other.So define onclick method for button

```
   button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Animation.class);
               startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
                    startActivity(intent);
               overridePendingTransition  (R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
            }
        });
```

Step 2:Now define the animation that you need for the second activity while launching

anim.right_slide_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="700"
        />
</set>
```

Comment: Causing layout of previous activity to turn black during animation.