# Material Design Animation - GridView item to Detail Screen

Tags: android, animation, material-design

I want to achieve something like the below in my application. What is this animation called? any examples for the same will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is android material design animation (transitions).
Instead of real animation, you can define two layouts, and the android OS animate the layout change to you.

article :
http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/animation/meaningful-transitions.html#meaningful-transitions-visual-continuity

read this, you can see similar animation here:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

http://java.dzone.com/articles/material-design-activity

[Android Material design transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24996723/android-material-design-transitions)

If you would like to support backward compatibility as well, this is your library:
https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere

Answer (score 0):

All Material Design animations are now achievable through the new RecyclerView .

RecyclerView is the replacement for ListView/GridView. As you want GridView animations per Material Design , you should use RecyclerView now.

RecyclerView has ItemAnimator, through which you can achieve your animation.

[See the official doc on this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.html)

If you are new to RecyclerView, then first see a simple implementation and then proceed. [RecyclerView example](http://simplestandroidtutorial.blogspot.in/2015/06/easiest-recyclerview-example.html)